# Get Current Input's Parent Class - JEditable / JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I'm trying to get the class of the parent element of the currently focussed input. All the inputs have a class of .edit (that JEditable binds to). The parent class states which controller, field and id are used in the database update (I'm using Codeigniter with JQuery Ajax).

Here's my current code:

```
var basepath;

 $(document).ready(function() {
    basepath = "/mm/";
    jedit();
});

function jedit() {
    $('#container').live({
    click: function() {

        $('.edit').focus(function() {
          var attributes    = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
        });

        var splitResult = attributes.split("-");
        var controller  = splitResult[0];
        var field       = splitResult[1];
        var id          = splitResult[2];

        $('.edit').editable(basepath+controller+'/edit/'+field+'/'+id,{
        indicator:'<img src="'+basepath+'images/throbber.gif">'
        });

        }
    });
}
```

Currently I get `attributes is not defined` in the firebug console. I think this is because until the text to edit is clicked on, the input doesn't exist (so there is no focus). I've tried an `if else` along the lines of:

```
if($('.edit input').length != 0) {
  var attributes    = $('.edit').closest('tr').attr('class');
} else {
  var attributes    = 'some nul thing here';  
}
```

But that just always evaluates to false.

Any ideas or suggestions about how to get the parent class of the active .edit class, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're declaring `attributes` inside that [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) handler *only* (so it won't be available in the higher `click` scope.

Instead, it should be defined in the scope you want to use it, the *set* it in that event handler, like this:

```
var attributes;
$('.edit').focus(function() {
   attributes = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
});
```

However, in your case you'll want to use this data *when the focus happens*, overall looking like this:

```
function jedit() {
    $('#container').delegate('.edit', 'focus', function() {  
       var result = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class').split("-"),
           controller  = result[0],
           field       = result[1],
           id          = result[2];
       $(this).editable(basepath+controller+'/edit/'+field+'/'+id,{
           indicator:'<img src="'+basepath+'images/throbber.gif">'
       });
    });
}
```

Also, as an aside, unless the `class` is useful for *other* reasons, e.g. styling...consider using a [`data-` attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) specifically for data, rather than the browser trying to find/apply a CSS class here.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply. This looks like a really good answer, but seems to break JEditable - no errors, just the input doesn't appear on click.

Comment: This works perfectly now, I just changed 'focus' to click. Thanks!

Comment: And +1 for data-attribute, I'd never heard of that.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, are you looking for something different?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form class="pelement">
    <input type="text" class="editable" value="some value here" />
</form>


<script language="javascript">
    $('.editable').focus(function(){
        console.log("parent: %s", $(this).parent().attr('class'));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this works, as an example...you've completely removed all of what the OP is doing with their code, and removing the problem at the same time.

Comment: Based on the poster's subject, my belief is that you should focus an answer on their exact question, as quite often the additional details can be what is causing confusion. I'm happy to respond further to questions if they request more information, but I prefer to try and focus on the topic.

Comment: @whoughton - The topic was `attributes` not being defined, you've left it completely out of the answer/code...

Comment: Forgive me, perhaps we see something different, but I see, "Get Current Input's Parent Class - JEditable / JQuery / Javascript"

Comment: @whoughton - That's the *title* yes, what about the rest of the question where the OP actually describes the problem? :)

Comment: That's my point though, your title should be your pointed question. The post itself should be details, but your primary concern should be in the title, as such that's what I focused on. Again, if it's not, I'm happy to work with the person on follow-ups, but I'm normally of a "keep it simple" mindset.

Comment: @whoughton - I *totally* disagree with you here, that's not how SO works...the title should be descriptive (and it is) but totally ignoring the other 30,000 bytes allowed in the question makes most answers completely off-point, as it does in this specific case as well...your answer has *very* little to do with the problem.  Even considering *only* the title, where's your use of jEditable?

Comment: I can understand both your points, however I'm inclined to agree with Nick. Can we not go off both the title and details? I struggle to explain most coding problems in a short sentence.

Comment: I am honestly not diametrically opposed to Nick, I think he makes a good point, all things considered, I knew I was really scratching the surface by saying, "This works for me, are you looking for something different?" But I do also think that starting simple and getting more detailed can make sense in many cases.

Comment: @whoughton No I understand, I think that is a valid approach, it's just a little less thorough. Personally I'd prefer an answer tailored to my particular problem. Though I can see that your approach addresses the fact the many problems in coding are repeated by different people, and a quick solution could solve that. Yeah, nothing to fall out over.

Comment: Wow, I am horrible with run-on sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The click on your `#container` will steal focus from whatever input was previously focused, so you are going to have to somehow store the last focused on `.edit` input:

```
var basepath, lastFocus;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit").focus(function(){ lastFocus = $(this); });

    basepath = "/mm/";
    jedit();
});


function jedit() {
    $('#container').live({
    click: function() {
        /* EDIT: In case lastFocus is null: */

       if(lastFocus == null) return;

        var attributes = lastFocus.closest('tr').attr('class');

        var splitResult = attributes.split("-");
        var controller  = splitResult[0];
        var field       = splitResult[1];
        var id          = splitResult[2];

        $('.edit').editable(basepath+controller+'/edit/'+field+'/'+id,{
            indicator:'<img src="'+basepath+'images/throbber.gif">'
        });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. This gives me a similar problem, I'm getting a `lastFocus is undefined` as the .edit input only exists once the text is clicked on. I think.

Comment: So then, what would you like to do in the case that there was no focused `.edit`?

Comment: Thanks for the try, I couldn't quite get this to work. Excellent effort though.